# Using Gorm model with custom sequence

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have a seq 'user_tfa_info_seq' which I want to use in 'user_tfa_info' table in Gorm Model.

I used the following structure, but it does not work.

```
type UserTfaInfo struct{
  ID        uint `gorm:"primary_key;type:bigint(20) not null" sql:"nextval('user_tfa_info_seq')"`
}
```

Comment: After looking for some hours, I thing may be gorm does not have this feature. So, what can be used is linking the seq with the primary key in db, for example
`ALTER TABLE user_tfa_info ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('user_tfa_info_seq');`
or 
`ALTER TABLE user_tfa_info
 ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;`